# Usage of 快到碗里来 to mean "bring it on"?

Tags: grammar

Can this be used to express "bring it on".

I want to list some things that may lie in the future and finish with bring it on.

Like: Hard times, good times, happiness, sadness, bring it on.

Can I use 快到碗里来 in this way ?

Comment: That's an unorthodox way of using "bring it on"...

Comment: "快到碗里来" is a meme from an ad of M&M's. It's associated with a metaphore "你是我的菜" (You are my dish. You are my cup of tea.) Since "you" are my dish, hurry and come to my bowl, which expresses that I like/love you.

Comment: 快到碗里来 sounds like an imminent fight / tryst between two dumplings.

Comment: @ElpieKay Yes. Therefore, you have to have the two parts together. "你是我的菜，快到碗里来" - means I love you and you are mine. Please come into my arms right now.

Comment: No, 快到碗里来 does not mean "bring it on". It means "Bring yourself to come to me".

Comment: @PdotWang Not necessary to explicitly use "你是我的菜".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Base on the comments, 快到碗里来  is equivalent to "Let's get it on" in English

~

The idiom for "Bring it on" is [放馬過來](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%94%BE%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%8E%E4%BE%86), not 快到碗里来 (hurry and  get into the bowl) which sounds like someone talking to his food

Maybe a mishear or someone making a joke

> Hard times, good times, happiness, sadness, bring it on.

> 艱難的時光，美好的時光，快樂的時光，悲傷的時光，放馬過來吧！

We usually use the term "放馬過來 (bring it on)" when accepting challenges, "good times and happiness" don't sound like a challenge

Better example:

國家領導人：「通漲，水災，國際制裁，放馬過來吧！我都給你接下！」

National leaders: "Inflation, floods, international sanctions, let's bring it on! I'll take care of them all for you!"

Comment: I remember many years ago there was a swine fever outbreak, and the joke was 放猪過來 :)

Comment: "which sounds like someone talking to his food". really? Chinese can almost talk about any topic as something to eat. :-) :-). This is actually a song about his gf.

Answer (score 2):

"bring it on" is tough guy speech, "I'm not afraid of anything, bring it on!"

Easiest is: 来吧

or

随时奉陪

or

奉陪到底

快到碗里来 seems to be the name of a computer game.

Comment: Thought the same :)

Comment: 快到碗里来 is from a song, then was used by a commercial.